# Make POST API Request Without Allowing Other People Access

Tags: javascript, express

I am trying to code a website where the user inputs information and it is passed to the backend (node.js/express.js) by the JavaScript. I don't want just anyone to be able to POST the JSON to the server, just the website's code. I am not sure how to do this as I can't use authorisation keys because that would be available as the code is client-side.

The server is using express.js run on node.js and the frontend is just JavaScript triggered from an HTML file.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by just the website's code? And also what have you tried till now.

Comment: Everything your website sends to the server your client will be able to see, you cannot prevent this. To prevent malicious POST requests to the endpoint you will need to protect your API endpoint in some way.

Comment: @adzo261 I don't want people to be able to send my app JSON data I don't want, and preferably stop people performing requests outside of the website. I would use an auth key but the client side reveals it. I was wondering if there was some other way.

Comment: “*I can't use authorisation headers because that would be available as the code is client-side.*” Can you maybe explain your understanding on how *every other authenticated form on the Internet* works?

Comment: @esqew I meant just using an auth key wouldn't work as it would then be publicly available, didn't mean header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: you can't.

Long answer:

Once your API is public on the Internet, everything can connect to it as long as it has network capabilities. Telnet, HTTP, Go program, Node.js scripts, Python scripts, etcetera.

You can limit your API access by using CORS policy, authorization header, user-agent header, referrer header, rate limiter and the like, but it's only a deterrent and everything can be spoofed by a malicious user.

In my opinion, you shouldn't worry about that, really. If you **really really want security**, and do not want others to access your API, consider implementing a user authentication system with JWT or sessions with secure cookies. It's the best way to protect your endpoints.

Check out these OWASP articles below to learn more about API security.

- [OWASP Top API](https://owasp.org/www-project-api-security/)
- [OWASP Safe REST](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet.html)

If you want to learn more about secure cookies and user authentication in Express, you can check the following articles:

- [Sending Cookies in Express](https://alligator.io/nodejs/express-cookies/)
- [Express Session Management](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/session-management-in-nodejs-using-expressjs-and-express-session/)
- [Implementing Secure, HTTPOnly Cookies](https://cheatcode.co/tutorials/how-to-implement-secure-httponly-cookies-in-node-js-with-express)

I also have one more good article, it's in Go, but you can adapt the concepts in Express.js as well. [Here's the link](https://www.calhoun.io/securing-cookies-in-go/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you have any good guides on using session cookies?

Comment: No problems at all. I have updated my previous answer so it contains the information that you requested. Oh, and please mark the answer as accepted if it helps you. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again. I will look at the links and then mark as accepted if they help.

Comment: Just another quick question, how should I store the session IDs?

Comment: You can store them with in-memory store (use global variables - but this is not really recommended) if it's a small application. If you wish to scale up, you can use open-source caching solutions like Redis or even a conventional database. I prefer Redis though, as it's basically designed for stuff like these (Redis is super fast!)